# Extrapolate max values from a dataset based on a date

Tags: python, pandas

I am given the following dataset as shown in the image and I am asked to print the City and country on the 2020-02-04 in which the value was the highest and the second highest.
Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by combining the methods where, sort_values and iloc of pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# reproduce your data
city = ['milan', 'barcelona', 'madrid', 'palermo']
country = ['italy', 'spain', 'spain', 'italy']
value = [-2, 5, 8, -1.5]
date = pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-04', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-05'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    zip(city, country, value, date),
    columns=['city', 'country', 'value', 'date']
)

# define target date
tdate = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-04')

# sort according to value column -> highest on top
df = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)

# filter for date
df = df.where(df.date == tdate)

# print 2 highest values (after sorting this means the first 2)
print(df.iloc[:2][['city', 'country']])

# or as single command
print(
        df
        .where(df.date == tdate)
        .sort_values('value', ascending=False)
        .iloc[:2][['city', 'country']]
)
```

output:

```
        city country
2     madrid   spain
1  barcelona   spain
```